# How to set a models attribute based on a parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to set an attribute on a child model when its parent is changed

Here is an example:

```
create_table "children", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "parent_id"
  t.string  "parent_type"
  t.integer "foo_id"
end

create_table "fathers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "foo_id"
end

create_table "mothers", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "foo_id"
end

create_table "foos", :force => true do |t|
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Mother < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Now, when I execute the following, I want child.foo_id to be set from parent:

```
foo = Foo.new {|foo| foo.id = 1}
parent = Father.new {|father| father.foo = foo}
child = Child.new
child.parent = parent
```

I need `foo_id` to be set right away, not in a `before_validation` callback or anything like that.

This is a simplified example, in the real case I have many more polymorphic types.  I know this can be accomplished with an `after_add` callback on a `has_many` association on Father and Mother, but I'd rather not have to add a has_many association if possible since that requires me to add code in many more places.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: is foo_id working like foreign key?

Comment: I think the question is why NOT use a `has_many :children` in Parent? Won't that come in handy in other ways, too?

Comment: I updated the example to add a belongs_to relationship for foo, which I forgot to add initially.

Comment: what is foo_id? its purpose? can't you use that as foreign key for polymorphic?

Comment: foo_id is just a pointer to another model (Foo) that all the other models belong to, I'll update the example accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand what you want to achieve.

May be this

```
parent = Parent.new(foo_id=>123456)
child = Child.new(:parent=>parent,:foo_id=>parent.foo_id)

if parent.save
   child.save
end
```

or

```
parent = Parent.new(foo_id=>123456)

if parent.save
   Child.create(:parent=>parent,:foo_id=>parent.foo_id)
end
```

Comment: I don't want to have to set foo_id directly, I want it to be set automatically when I set parent

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this would work but maybe you could overwrite the setter for `parent` in the `Child` model

```
def parent=(p)
  self.foo_id = p.foo_id
  super(p)
end
```